# Move view from UITableViewCell to Window and back to same cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating an SDK where I have a view that performs various tasks such as expanding and flipping to not go into much detail.

In one possible use case, the user may place the view in a UITableViewCell. To make the expand work properly, I have the view be removed from superview and added as a subview of the window. As so:

```
[mySDKView removeFromSuperview];

UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

if (!window) {
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}

[window addSubview:mySDKView];
```

Now I need to figure out how to put it back into the table cell! Either automatically so it is abstracted for the user (preferred) or an implementation I can leave in a doc for them to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon expand, store the superview of mySDKView (named savedSuperView below).

Upon unexpand do:

```
if (savedSuperView) {
    [savedSuperView addSubview:mySDKView];
} else {
    [viewController.view addSubview:mySDKView];
}
```